# Trying to understand suspension of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, spheres

I'm trying to understand the suspension of a topological space:
According to **Wikipedia** The suspension of a topological space $X$ is the quotient space 
$SX=(X \times I )/ \{(x_1,0) ~(x_2,0)$ and $ (x_1,1)~(x_2,1) \forall x_1,x_2 \in X \}$,$I$ is unit interval.

To understand the definition properly I'm trying some examples.Now if $X=S^n$ (n-sphere)then I can visualize that $SX$ is $ S^{n+1} $ but I'm unable in proving this rigorously.How should I prove this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On the existence of a continuous bijection from a quotient space to the unit sphere $S^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470081/on-the-existence-of-a-continuous-bijection-from-a-quotient-space-to-the-unit-sph). You could try to generalize the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of each "piece" of the cone as a disk. The suspension is the union of these two cones identified at their border. Then this union would look like the union of two closed balls of dimension n glued together at their borders which is presisely the n+1-dimensional sphere.